# colour based blob detection in open cv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to detect blobs based on colour in open cv for my image processing based project . But in the open cv function for blob detection they are converting the input BGR image to gray scale and then threshold the image causing the loss of colour information.

Code below is from the blob detection library.

```
if (image.channels() == 3)
        cvtColor(image, grayscaleImage, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    else
        grayscaleImage = image.getMat();

    if (grayscaleImage.type() != CV_8UC1) {
        CV_Error(Error::StsUnsupportedFormat, "Blob detector only supports 8-bit images!");
    }
```

Is there any method for colour based blob detection ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can easily segment out the color blobs using the opencv [cv::inRange](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#inrange) method, which would yield a single channel binary mask for the pixels falling in the specified range. The main advantage of using [inRange](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#inrange) lies in the fact that you can segment all types of Mats i.e. `grayScale, RGB, RGBA`. It can be used as follows:

```
image = cv::imread("./sample.png"); // For reading the image in RGB format
//image = cv::imread("./sample.png", -1) // For reading the image in existing format
cv::Mat segmented_image;
// For segmenting the image in RGB format.
cv::inRange(image, cv::Scalar(100, 10, 60), cv::Scalar(120, 50, 70), segmented_image);

// For segmenting the image in Gray format
cv::inRange(image, cv::Scalar(110), cv::Scalar(150), segmented_image);

// For segmenting the image in RGBA format
cv::inRange(image, cv::Scalar(100, 10, 60, 10), cv::Scalar(120, 50, 70, 250), segmented_image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Handle the conversion from color image to grayscale yourself. For example, if you want red objects, take only the red channel, and search the blobs there.

Usually, it is better to move from RGB into HSV (Hue, Saturation, Value). The hue channel should give you a better color seperation. (see [HSV and HSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV))

```
cv::cvtColor(image, imgHSV, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);
cv::inRange(imgHSV, Scalar(iLowH, iLowS, iLowV), Scalar(iHighH, iHighS, iHighV), imgThresholded);
```